# Add some sort of interface to a Dynamic.ExpandoObject object

Tags: c#, .net, expandoobject, flurl

I am using a library that return a `IList<dynamic>` (from a jsonArray), `dynamic` means not having any intellisense while using such object, I would like to be able to simply define what the dynamic object contains.

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`, then

Comment: What's your reason for using `dynamic` if you're aware of what the object contains?

Comment: can you cast each item to the interface-type? `myList.Cast<InterfaceType>()`

Comment: @msmolcic How can i not use dynamic ? that is what the method returns: `A Task whose result is the JSON response body deserialized to a list of dynamics.`

Comment: @HimBromBeere i tried but i obviously am doing something wrong, i get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to type ..`

Comment: how do you deserialize the JSON?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not, it is not my code, from what i can gather, the library (`Flurl`) uses  `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(stream)`

Comment: @HimBromBeere ok i think i found out, i was able to provide my own class for the deserialization using another method of the library, i guess snooping around the code trying to answer you helped (reading other's code is not my forte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're calling some `https://dummy-url.com/something` endpoint which returns the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "firstProp": "First value",
        "secondProp": "Second value",
        "intProp": 1337
    },
    {
        "firstProp": "Another first value",
        "secondProp": "Another second value",
        "intProp": 42
    }
]
```

You would then need to define a class in your program representing that JSON structure, such as:

```
public class Something
{
    public string FirstProp { get; set; }
    public string SecondProp { get; set; }
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, call that endpoint and deserialize its result to the object defined by your class:

```
public async IList<Something> FetchListOfSomething()
{
    var url = "https://dummy-url.com/something";
    return await url.GetJsonAsync<List<Something>>();
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what i did, found out i could provide `GetJsonAsync` with a paramter for the deserialization, i was originally using `GetJsonListAsync`.